# How to represent a high number of link in UML?

Tags: uml

I want to model a use case to show that if a PersonalTrainer object is linked to 20 Client objects, it cannot be linked to any more.

However, drawing 20 boxes and 20 association lines looks cumbersome and messy, what is the correct way to represent this use case in UML?

Comment: What type of diagram are you creating? You mention wanting to show a use case, but a use case diagram doesn't show objects. It sounds like you want to create an object diagram, or maybe a communication diagram.

Comment: … In particular, use case diagrams do not describe use cases. They show which actors are involved in which use case, and sometimes how use cases relate to each other. The only good use I've seen for use case diagrams is to serve as an index of all use cases, which are then described as text at some other place.

Comment: Will your system fail to meet the use case if there are 19 or 21 clients?

Answer (score 4):

[Use case diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html) represent a system under consideration (a box), actors (stickmen or boxes) and use-cases (elipses), the actors being linked to use cases.  For example:
[image]

Obviously, what you're describing can't be a use case: a use case doesn't know objects, nor links between objects.  So I think that you're talking about another diagram related to a use case you're implementing.  You may then make an [object diagram or a class diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html). Normally you'd start with the latter.

If you make a class diagram, it's easy to show the maximum number of relations between `PersonalTrainer` and `Client` by putting a [multiplicity](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html?context=class-diagrams) `0..20` on the link on the side of the `Client`.

[image]

If you really want to make an object diagram, it won't represent a general case anymore, but a specific scenario (snapshot) involving object instances.  So you have then to represent an instance of `PersonalTrainer`, and draw all its individual clients at the moment of time (snapshot) you're documenting.

[image]

Well, then if you choose a successful trainer having already 20 clients, the you have to draw the 20 individual clients.

Comment: Hi, sorry my terminology is a little off. I did indeed mean an object diagram. Thanks for taking the time to flesh out a detailed response :)